# How to use filtering of prices on the list of products that come from shortcode in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

**Introduction:**

Woocommerce uses `$_GET` variables such as `min_price` and `max_price` to filter the prices. It works on the default list of products (e.g. search results, products from the category, etc.)

For example: `https://website.com/category/clothing/?min_price=20&max_price=100`

**The problem:**

`$_GET` variables such as `min_price` and `max_price` do not work when displaying products on the page using shortcode

Shortcode example: `[products ids="36,35,96,95,68,6,62,9369,61,24,26" paginate="true" limit="30"]`

And the URL: `https://website.com/custom-page-with-shortcode/?min_price=20&max_price=100`

**The question:**

Is there a way to "activate" price filtering when using shortcode?

I tried to analyze how this works in the `class-wc-widget-price-filter.php` but with no success.

Is exist any filter or action that I should refer to? I'm not sure where I should look for it

Comment: Consider moving you question to the wordpress SE... https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: On SE, they closed the question because they treat WooCommerce as off-topic ‍♂️